# Should I generate the content first then display SaveDialog or vice versa?

Tags: .net, winforms, mvp

I have a .NET Winforms application (MVP) pattern. I have a feature wherein a user can save a content into his/her local directory. Here are the two approach for implementation:

1. Click the button, pop a save dialog, and when user clicks save, display loading, then call the function that generates the content and saves it on the path chosen, close the loading afterwards.
2. Click the button, display loading, call the function that generates the content, persist the generated content, close the loading, pop a save dialog and when the user clicks save, save the content on the path chosen.

## 1 Pro: In contrast to #2, I don't have to "persist" the generated content, because I am able to save the file right away upon generating it.

## 1 Con: After clicking save, there is a loading time during the generation and saving of the content. It "feels" unnatural on UX.

## 2 Pro: Expected to have minimal to no loading time when the user clicks on save, because the content is already ready.

## 2 Con: I have to persist the generated content until the user clicks on save, since I am going back to the View to pop the save dialog, the content must be persisted, I think a big bulk of content seems weird to carry across MVP.

I am inclined to #2, especially if there is another way to "persist" the content or implement the generate content first then save dialog.

Comment: Option 1 personally makes more sense as if the user cancels the save dialog then you have generated content you don't need. Simple show a saving message to the user so they understand there is something happening. This is really just an opinion. Cheers

Comment: @Nico thank you, that is one good factor considering option 1.

Comment: I second Nico's response.  Best to not do the work until you're certain it is necessary.

Comment: Thirded. Nothing makes me madder than when I click the wrong button mistakenly and am punished by having to sit and wait for the application.